# Slim Framework .htaccess forward

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

There are several questions out there to that topic, but not a single one did match my question, because I am using Slim Framework 3.

One of my routes, for example, is /stats
When I make requests to http://localhost/slim-app/public/stats - it works.
But, I want to make requests to http://localhost/slim-app/stats - and that doesn't work. Slim gives me the error

> Page Not Found The page you are looking for could not be found. Check
>   the address bar to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else
>   fails, you can visit our home page at the link below.

My folder structure looks like that:

```
/slim-app
 .htaccess
 /logs
 /public
  index.php
  .htaccess
 /src
  routes.php etc
 /templates
 /tests
 /vendor
```

The .htaccess- File inside the slim-app folder looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The .htaccess- File inside the public- folder  like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What should I change inside the htaccess- files to make it work? Thank you guys!

Comment: Your are making the app object in slim-app/public/index.php. all routes will be decided here. you can't make the request outside this directory.